# TCP/IP stack implementing files in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, tcp-ip

TCP/IP stack is implemented in ubuntu. Where are these files located in ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Which files? configuration?

Answer (score 3):

You too have homework, like in “[what does ifconfig and eth0 do](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725808/what-does-ifconfig-and-eth0-do)” ? :-D

The TCP/IP stack is implemented in the kernel (Linux is a monolithic kernel). It's implemented as a separate module only with microkernels. So the files you are looking for, are most likely source files. On the other hand, following the UNIX spirit or “(nearly) everything is a file”, you may look for network items interface exposed as files or file handles (like sockets are). Both are presented here: [The TCP/IP Stack in the Linux Kernel](http://fr.slideshare.net/divyekapoor/linux-tcp-ip-presentation).